# How to use casl-vue in nuxt without refreshing page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, casl

I tried to use [casl-vue](https://github.com/stalniy/casl/tree/master/packages/casl-vue) for authorization in Nuxt.
Everything is ok but only after refreshing.

I used my own file as a plugin

```js
plugins: ['@/plugins/roles'],
```

my `roles` file

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Can, abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue'
import { defineAbility } from '@casl/ability'
Vue.component('Can', Can)

export default ({ $auth }) => {
  let abilities = defineAbility((can) => {
    console.log('s'+$auth.loggedIn)
    if ($auth.loggedIn) {
      $auth.user.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
        can(...permission)
      })
    }
  })
  Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin, abilities)
}
```

I checked `$auth.loggedIn` before login, it was `false`.
I tried checking it in the middleware, it was `true` there but it does not work in the plugin.

In login page, I manually changed `$auth.loggedIn` to `true` after login but it still does not work.
How could I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you installed the package for vue 2 ?

Comment: i installed this package
 ```    "@casl/ability": "^5.1.2",
    "@casl/vue": "^1.2.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function ({ $auth }) {
  const isLogin = $auth.loggedIn
  const abilities = defineAbility((can) => {
    if (isLogin) {
      const user = $auth.user
      can(user.permissions)
    } else {
      can([])
    }
  })

  Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin, abilities)
}
```

Comment: Code only answers may help the OP, but to be precise, and make full use of this platform, do add some explanation, at least a comment.